# memory error when I used more than 1 CPU for BaggindRegressor

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

When using the BaggingRegressor model, setting n_jobs to 1 results in successful training, but when attempting to train with 6 CPUs (n_jobs >1), the memory usage increases in each iteration.  It seems the memory usage does not release in each iteration automatically.  The code is as follows,

```
    test1= np.empty((788,))
    test2= np.empty((788,))
    pred_test= np.empty((788,))

    for y in np.arange(0, 71, 1):
        for x in np.arange(0, 73, 1):

            dataY = rawdata[y, x, :]/10
            dataX= (fx + fxa)/2

            dataX = np.reshape(dataX , (4017, 1))
            dataY = np.reshape(dataY , (4017, 1))

            u = np.argwhere(np.isnan(dataY))
            dataY = np.delete(dataY, u)
            dataX= np.delete(dataX, u)
            l = len(dataY)
            dataY= np.reshape(dataY, (l, 1))
            dataX= np.reshape(dataX, (l, 1))

            X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
                dataX, dataY, test_size=0.20)

            xgb_reg = xgb.XGBRegressor()
            model = BaggingRegressor(
                base_estimator=xgb_reg, n_jobs=1, n_estimators=100)

            model.fit(X_train, y_train.ravel())
            pred_final = model.predict(X_test)

            # assign data into list
            test1[:] = np.squeeze(y_test)
            test2[:] = np.squeeze(X_test)
            pred_test[:] = np.squeeze(pred_final)

            del xgb_reg, model, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, dataY, dataX, u, l, pred_test
            gc.collect()
```

Using multiple CPUs appears to be causing a memory issue, while using only 1 CPU does not seem to have this problem.

I am not sure if there is a problem in BaggingRegressor.
How can I train the model using multiple CPUs without causing memory issues?